# CWinApp CFrameWindow not shown

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

i'm trying to create window using CFrameWindow, i used code from "Simulation for applied graph theory using Visual C++" but it didn't had entry point, so it doesn't work any way. So i simplified it as much as i could and now when application is launched in release mode window doesn't appear and in debug mode it throws error that assertion failed. I used MSVS Visual C++ -> General -> Empty project with "Use of MFC" set to Use MFC in a Shared DLL.

Here is the code :

```
#include <afxwin.h>

class MyWnd : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    MyWnd()  { Create(0, "MyWnd"); }
    ~MyWnd() { }
};

class MyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        m_pMainWnd = new MyWnd;
        m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);
        return TRUE;
    }
};

int CALLBACK WinMain (_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    MyApp myApp;
    myApp.InitInstance();
    myApp.Run();
}
```

EDIT: updated to call MyApp.Run(), but it still doesn't display anything, also checked Subsystem, none was selected, tried Console, Windows, Native, compiled only with Windows but didn't help.

Comment: Which subsystem-type do you use ( see project-proerties -> linker -> system -> subsystem ).

Comment: Subsystem: none was selected, tried Console, Windows, Native, compiled only with Windows but didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it displays blank white window with titlebar when i make myApp global with myApp.Run() or without it.

EDIT: It worked on my laptop win10, but on pc win7 same code didn't work, so on pc in project properties -> character set was Multibyte, after changing it to Unicode, it started showing window on pc also.

Answer (score 2):

After InitInstance you should call CWinApp::Run in order to start message pumping.
Also, Run() blocks the WinMain function until it exits. Without Run(), your WinMain simply terminates before you see the window.

Comment: now i can see it in task manager, but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: No window frame at all? No close-minimize-maximize buttons?